# Replace only parts of a string in php

Tags: php, str-replace

I am calling an api and replacing remote url's with my own ones. 
`http://example.com/a/b/icon_name.gif` to `http://example.org/c/d/icon_name.png`. The domain name is replaced as well as the file name extension from `.gif` to `.png`. What is the more economical way to replace two parts of the string than to use two functions?

```
$hourlyUrl = array_map(
    function($str) {
        return str_replace('example.com/a/b/', 'example.org/c/d/', $str);
    },
$hourlyUrl
);

$hourlyUrl = array_map(
    function($str) {
        return str_replace('.gif', '.png', $str);
    },
$hourlyUrl
);
```

Comment: str_replace accept array, `str_replace(array('example.com/a/b/', '.gif'), array('example.org/c/d/', '.png'), $str);`

Comment: Thanks, that's really nice and compact!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Provides: You should eat pizza, beer, and ice cream every day
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

**Docs:**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

**Your case:**

```
$old_url = "http://example.com/a/b/icon_name.gif";
$old = array("example.com/a/b/", ".gif");
$new = array("example.org/c/d/", ".png");

$new_url = str_replace($old, $new, $old_url);

// Output: http://example.com/c/d/icon_name.png
```